# Use React Context in Custom Document (Next.js)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a problem with accessing the React Context object in my Custom Document page (Next.js).

Since I am working on a cookie banner for GDPR purpose, I want to use the React Context state in order to prevent the analytic scripts to be fired in the Custom Document page, if the GDPR is not accepted by the user.

However, I cannot figure out how to access the React Context state within my custom _document.js page.
Is that possible at all?

Or is there another good way in next.js how I can implement the GDPR Cookie Banner?

Many thanks in advance!

JP

Comment: Context will only be available to the children of your context provider, which would generally wrap your <Component {...pageProps} /> in _app.js. I would consider using the the new next/script component as referenced here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script and load it within your pages, or create a layout wrapper that is shared among all of your pages.

Comment: `_document` is only rendered in the server, move your logic to `_app` instead.